# Django: broken migrations

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-south, django-1.4

I am trying to setup a Django app locally in a new machine but migrations seem to be totally broken. They need to be performed in a particular order, which worked in the first machine I set the environment in a couple months ago, but now there are inconsistencies (although I am pretty sure no new migrations were generated).

So the only solution  I can think of is exporting the database from the old machine, where it is working, to the new one. Would that work?

This would not solve the broken migrations issue, but at least I can work on the code till there's a proper soltuion.

Comment: Did you try `makemigrations`? If you are changing models you have to first make add migrations package file inside the app. But, to automatically do that you have to be using `python manage.py makemigrations`.

Comment: Are you sure that both your installations run on the same Django versions? 1.4 is old and still uses South while Django >= 1.7 brings its own migration system (the replacement of South).

Comment: Yes, the old one uses 1.4 and it uses south migrations.

Comment: @iraycd `makemigrations` seem to be an unknown command. I guess it was introduced after 1.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this question:

> So the only solution I can think of is exporting the database from the old machine, where it is working, to the new one. Would that work?

Yes, this can work if you are sure that your database is in sync with your models. It is actually the way to go, if you want to be best prepared of updating your production environment.

1. get a dump from the current production machine
2. create a new database and load the dump
3. check whether there are differences between the models and the migration history (this is more reliable with the new Django migrations, South was an external tool and had not all of the possibilities) (e.g. `./manage.py showmigrations` (1.10), `./manage.py migrate --list` (1.7-1.9 and South)
4. If you are confident that no migrations have to be run but the listing shows differences then do: `./manage.py migrate --fake`

Note, in newer versions you can do `./manage.py migrate` and it will report that everything is in order if the models and the migrations are in sync. This can be a sanity check before you deploy onto production.